# KMZ displayed incorrectly on Google Maps, but looks good in Google Earth

Tags: google-maps, gis, kml, google-earth

As you can see my KML layer doesn't look good in Google Maps: https://maps.google.com/?q=https://sites.google.com/site/agri2agri/home/test1.kmz

It's obviously not stretched and wrong proportions. However, if I download this same KMZ (https://sites.google.com/site/agri2agri/home/test1.kmz) and I use Google Earth to view it, it views correctly.

What is happening?

Comment: The area it is defined to cover is wider than the diameter of the earth (430 degrees)    `<LatLonBox>
      <north>107.999210376</north>
      <south>-107.999928216</south>
      <east>215.998420752</east>
      <west>-215.999856432</west>
      <rotation>0</rotation>
    </LatLonBox>`, Google Earth must handle that better.

Comment: Looks like Google Earth treats that as 180 to -180.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks! you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area it is defined to cover is wider than the diameter of the earth (430 degrees)

```
<LatLonBox>
 <north>107.999210376</north>
 <south>-107.999928216</south>
 <east>215.998420752</east>
 <west>-215.999856432</west>
 <rotation>0</rotation>
</LatLonBox>
```

Google Earth must handle that better.